# display three div tag in one parent div tag

Tags: css, html

i want to display three div tag in a parent div tag
parent div has no width and height
one inner div will be on left side with fixed width and height
2nd inner div will be in center with fixed height only and its width is between two other div tags
3rd inner div will be on right side

```
 css
   #container{}
 #columnright{

    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height: 400px;
 }    
 #content{
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    height: 400px;
    }
 #columnleft{

    float:right;
    width:150px;
    height: 400px;
    }

 html
  <div id="container">
   <div id="columnright"></div>
   <div id="content"></div>
   <div id="columnleft"> </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Care to share a fiddle to illustrate what you're trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
#columnright{


    width:200px;
float:left;

 }    
 #content{

    width:200px;
float:left;


    }
 #columnleft{

float:left;
    width:150px;

    }

</style >
  <div id="container">
   <div id="columnright">hi</div>
   <div id="content">hello</div>
   <div id="columnleft">how</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't know why this is being upvoted. It does not answer the question. The asker said the center div's width is the space between the right and left divs -- not a set width as specified in this answer.

Comment: You're absolutely right...  See my answer below and result here:  http://jsfiddle.net/hdrenollet/dsbSt/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

```
 <style>

             #columnright
            {
                width: 200px;  
                height:400px;
    }

    #content
    {
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    }

    #columnleft
    {
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    height: 400px;
    }
</style>

<div id="container">
<div id="columnright"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="columnleft"></div>
</div>
```

I think the above code can help you. In the first inner div, no need to right float : left. Becoz u told that it must have fixed width and height. If u mention float property, it doesn't occupy the space.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hdrenollet/dsbSt/embedded/result/

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
    </script>
    <style>
        #parent{
            width:100%;
        }
        #columnleft{
            position:relative;
            float:left;
            border: 1px solid black;
            top:0px;
            width:150px;
            height: 400px;
        }
        #content{
            position:relative;
            width:100%;
            top:0px;
            padding: 20px;
            margin-left:150px;
            margin-right:200px;
        }
        #columnright{
            border: 1px solid black;
            float:right;
            top:0px;
            width:200px;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="parent">
   <div id="columnleft"></div>
   <div id="columnright"></div>
   <div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean lectus sem, lobortis fermentum eleifend non, interdum at orci. Ut nec mauris vulputate, eleifend elit vitae, suscipit felis. Etiam leo ligula, pellentesque non urna sed, sagittis hendrerit nibh. Sed pharetra pellentesque nunc vitae imperdiet. orci. Nam ac nisi sed ipsum ullamcorper aliquet eget lobortis enim. Duis consequat sed arcu vel vulputate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mollis porttitor sapien. Duis a sodales justo. Mauris gravida aliquet nunc in scelerisque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel nunc sagittis, dapibus quam eu, congue magna.</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You'll need to set your margin-left and margin-right of your content container to the widths of your left and right columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to youse CSS3's `calc()` function to calculate the width of your content div.
See here:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uPrbv/)

I also colored the divs for easier understanding. You should probably also remain your div's, because at the time your "columnright" is on the left hand side of the screen and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

This accomplishes what you're trying to do without floating anything. I also corrected your #columnright to actually be on the right side and your #columnleft to actually be on the left side. And I added background color to better illustrate what's going on.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="columnright"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="columnleft"> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#E0E0E0;
}

#columnleft {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:150px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:#CCCCE0;
}

#columnright {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:200px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:#E0CCCC;
}    

#content {
    margin-right:200px;
    margin-left:150px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color:#CCE0CC;
}
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/mNnAq/